# Is it correct to claim the existence of an 'indirect effect' in A>B>C chain when no significant A>C path is found? Or what else should I call it?

Tags: factor-analysis, structural-equation-modeling, mediation, lavaan, amos

I am working on a SEM where I hypothesize a causal chain where A influences B, which in turn influences C. The data are from a 2x2 between-subjects experiment, N = 297.

All the goodness of fit indices look very good:
chi-square p-value = .07
CFI = .991
TLI = .989
RMSEA = .028, PCLOSE = .992
Both the A>B path and the B>C path are significant, as predicted.

Now, here is my problem. The A>C path is not significant, neither before nor after adding the B variable. Based on this:

1. Would it be correct to claim that A has "an indirect effect" on C? Or what would be a more correct description?
2. Is this a case of mediation or of some other form of indirect effect?
3. Should there always be a A>C path in models with indirect effects of this kind?

Thanks so much in advance for your kind help!

Matteo

Comment: This paper might be useful: http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/0956797613502676?url_ver=Z39.88-2003&rfr_id=ori%3Arid%3Acrossref.org&rfr_dat=cr_pub%3Dpubmed& It explains some of your findings.